# How can I split a Django model into multiple models that inherit from the first

Tags: django, inheritance

I have a Django model used extensively in my app. I'd like to create another model that inherits from that one so I can continue using the original model throughout the code, but move a field to the new model

I have:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):   
   field1 =...  
   field2=... 
   field3=...
```

I want to move field3 to a new model:

```
class MyModel2(MyModel):
   field3=...
```

Then I'd like MyModel instances where field3 is not null to become MyModel2 instances.

The code would continue to refer to MyModel, but in some special cases, I'd use MyModel2 instead. Is this possible? Advisable? Is there a better way? I considered making a base abstract model that both could inherit from, but then you can't use the abstract model in forms and things.

Actual model:

```
class Unit(models.Model):
   address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Unit Name")
   payments = GenericRelation("Payment", content_type_field='content_type', object_id_field='object_pk')
   permissions = GenericRelation("CustomPermission", content_type_field='content_type', object_id_field='object_pk')
   association = models.ForeignKey(Association, blank=True, null=True)


def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

"association" is the field I want to move to another model.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use `abstract = True` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 =...
    field2=... 
    field3=...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class MyModel2(MyModel):
    field4=...


class AssociationBase(models.Model):
    association = models.ForeignKey(Association, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Unit(AssociationBase):
   address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Unit Name")
   payments = GenericRelation("Payment", content_type_field='content_type', object_id_field='object_pk')
   permissions = GenericRelation("CustomPermission", content_type_field='content_type', object_id_field='object_pk')


    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: I tried that, and then I couldn't use MyModel in a form. I got this error: AttributeError: type object 'MyModel' has no attribute '_default_manager'

Comment: Please provide the real full code of your MyModel and MyModel2 because it may be that you use some custom manager or something else. By default models have default object manager